# In bazaar, how do I change the default target of "bzr push"?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, bazaar

`bzr push` defaults to the first target you pushed to. If I now want to push to a different location, but don't want to manually enter it every time, how do I change the default?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I figured it out. You do:

```
bzr push --remember [location]
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for coming back to answer your own question, very helpful.